# Loop through posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to loop through all my posts and put the banner links into an array eg

```
Array ("link1.jpg","link2.jpg","link3.jpg")
```

heres my code:

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'banners' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <?php echo '"' .get_field('image'). '"';?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

thats fine and echo's out the list correctly but how do I put that into a variable?

```
eg. $variable =  ("link1.jpg","link2.jpg","link3.jpg")
```

Comment: Please do not vanalise your post once you've got an answer.

Comment: you have contradicted your original requirement, first you wanted a variable string now you want an array

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's `explode` function.

When you output everything, save it into a variable.

Then, `$images = explode(",", $images);` will produce this:

`Array ( [0] => image1.jpg [1] => image2.jpg [2] => image3.jpg [3] => image4.jpg )`

To output this, you can then use `$images[number]` for each image.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'banners' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
var $my_arr = array();

foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); 
     $my_arr[] = get_field('image');
endforeach;

print_r($my_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store them in an array :

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'banners' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
$links = array();
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <?php $links[] = get_field('image');?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
global $post;
$image_array = array();
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'banners' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <?php $image_array[] = get_field('image');?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

adjust your code as follows.

```
<?php
 global $post;
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'banners' );
 $myposts = get_posts( $args );
$array = array(); 
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); 
     $image '"' .get_field('image'). '"';
     echo $image;
     $array[] = $image;
 endforeach;

 $variable = implode(",", $array);
```

Pretty much saving a copy of `$image` into an array called `array` and then using the php function `implode` which glues array elements using the string provided, in this case the string is `","`.